# In excel, get the ratio of a column grouped by the data in another column

Tags: excel

Consider the data:

```
Player | Win/Lose
-----------------
David  | W
David  | L
David  | W
Steve  | L
Steve  | L
```

I need to calculate the win ratio for each player that is inputted (I don't know how many players there are). I could this using MySQL but I'm unsure how this translates to excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the formula countifs with david and W and divide by countif with david and

Comment: Could you provide an example? I need it to do it for all the players, and not that I just put down a player.

Comment: Assuming that player is column A and Win/Lose is column B, create a new column C with header W/L Ratio and add this formula in cell C2 `=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2)/COUNTIFS(A:A,A2)'

Comment: Sure that works for David, but what about Steve? How would I change it for him?

Comment: it will change for any number of names, once u have pasted in cell C2, just drag the formula to how many ever rows u want. there's no limit. it will change for each player and will give u both the winratio and lossratio for each.